# How do I Convert FLAC files to ALAC for iTunes?

Tags: macos, itunes, audio

I have a pretty large music library in [FLAC](http://flac.sourceforge.net/), and I need to import it to my iTunes library somehow. I want to use the [ALAC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apple_Lossless) format to keep everything lossless so I can transcode to different lossy formats later if I need to.

Comment: @ShaneHsu Obviously you did not read the question.

Comment: It was quite dark. LOL My bad.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Have a look at [Max](http://sbooth.org/Max/). Freeware and Open source. Has a GUI.

Comment: Glad it worked for you. YW

Comment: You may run into issues with Max crashing if you don't have Growl installed. Last time I had to install this, I had to get the source and compile it myself, but it may be fixed in the "dev" version (or even the "stable") by now. Just a heads up if you're getting any crashes.

Comment: 2018 Update: I still use Max for this exact job. It's very buggy under new OS's but luckily for me I do my compression work on a Mac Pro that can also boot 10.7. Max works great under that.

Comment: 2021 Update: Download the beta to run on a current version of macOS.

Answer (score 5):

I'm a fan of [XLD](http://tmkk.undo.jp/xld/index_e.html) and since the original question was posed it gained the drag-and-drop folder capabilities that the person asking the question as after. No need to install Growl to get it to work. It also handles embedded images in FLAC files when doing the conversion and will keep them in the ALAC output files.

Comment: This works (easily) for me on 10.15.7 while Max didn’t.

Answer (score 1):

You could also use ffmpeg:

```
for f in *.flac; do ffmpeg -i "$f" -c:a alac "${f%flac}m4a"; done
find . -name \*.flac | parallel ffmpeg -i {} -c:a alac {.}.m4a
```

It preserves common tags, but it doesn't currently preserve artwork.