# Converting FLAC into Apple Lossless [in Windows]

Tags: itunes, windows, audio

Like many people I have a few albums in FLAC format that I've picked up over the years. I'd like to retain their auto fidelity, but also have them in my iTunes and on my iPhone.

There's [another question here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/2451/how-do-i-convert-flac-files-to-alac-for-itunes) that asks the same question, but it's only asking how to convert files under **OSX**. I'd like to do it under **Windows**.

Is this possible?

Comment: Since iTunes can't read flac, you are going to need another 3rd party Windows program to do the task, which is off topic according to http://apple.stackexchange.com/faq

Comment: Even with iTunes involved this is only faintly related to Apple products as described in the [faq]. So you are better off with asking this on a more windows oriented site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a great little script that seems to do the job:

[iTunes Automation: Convert FLAC Audio Files to Apple Lossless](http://blog.dmitryleskov.com/small-hacks/itunes-automation-convert-flac-audio-files-to-apple-lossless/)

Although there's a tiny bug at present (v0.91) meaning it will only convert one file at a time. To fix it, just change line 275 from

```
fso.DeleteFile(tempWAVPath)
```

To

```
fso.DeleteFile(tempWAVPath, true)
```

And you're set.